# Website scraping: website search box has no value

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to crosscheck a large body of data with a specific website (https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx).

The goal is to search for many company names based on a larger list in Excel to get their founding dates. For now I am starting out with a single name to get it running. I am having trouble in my main code as there is no inherent input value in the HTML code:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$frmEntityName" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_frmEntityName" tabindex="4" size="30" maxlength="120" class="txtNormal" onkeyup="KeyEvent1(this.id)">
```

I tried the following:

```vb
Sub click_search()

Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set i = New InternetExplorer
i.Visible = True

i.Navigate "https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx"

Do While i.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set idock = i.Document

idoc.getElementsByTagName("input").Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$frmEntityName").Value = "10X Genomics Inc"

End Sub
```

The problem I believe is the HTML code does not have inherent value = "" to begin with but it only comes up in the HTML code after you write it in.

How do I fix this and furthermore then click the search button?

The error is

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always use Option Explicit** at the top of every VBA code file.

If the webpage in question contains ids for the elements you are interested in, use getElementById() to access them. This code works, however it does not find any records.

```
Option Explicit
Sub click_search()
Dim i As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim idoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set i = New InternetExplorer
i.Visible = True
i.Navigate "https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx"

Do While i.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set idoc = i.Document
idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_frmEntityName").Value = "10X Genomics Inc"
idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_frmFileNumber").Value = "1"
idoc.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: This still yields the same error:
object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I edited my question but I still receive the same error despite using the Set as your code.

Comment: Always use Option Explicit at the very top of every code document. If you'd used that you'd found a typo: Set idock = i.Document. Correct the typo and it's working!

Comment: The code above works. Please be a gentleman and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks a lot for the help!